# Require.js require context

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs, require

Suppose that I need **test** variable when I'm inside the require statement. Which is the best approach, if exists, in order to access the variable that I need? Is there a way to change context?

```
    somefunction: function(id) {
        var test ="xxx";
        require(['models/Model', 'views/View'], function(ArticleModel, ArticleView) {
            var collection = new Collection();
// I need to access the TEST variable HERE
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just use it. It'll be there. Read up on JavaScript `closures`; it captures the variable for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you included, you will be able to use the 'test' variable, as it was defined in a scope that encompasses the call to require().

Here's another StackOverflow answer that explains this in more detail -- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)